# JFreeChart : How to display hours format on the y axis

Tags: charts, jfreechart

I can't find how to modify the label of the y axis.
For now I use a TimeSeries with the MINUTE class, and then insert the TimeSeries into a Dataset.
It look like this :

```
   final TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Importation Time", Minute.class);
   s1.add(new Minute(dateFinal),concateHourAndMinuteToGetASingleValue);
   dataset.addSeries(s1);
```

What I would like to do is to modify the display label, and put a String (05h20 for exemple) instead of the Double value.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to set a `FormatOverride` on the `axis`.

Here is an example for both a `NumberAxis` and a `DateAxis`

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();

NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride( new NumberFormat(){

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(double number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
        return new StringBuffer(String.format("%f", number));
    }

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(long number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
        return new StringBuffer(String.format("%f", number));
    }

    @Override
    public Number parse(String source, ParsePosition parsePosition) {
        return null;
    }

} );
DateAxis domainAaxis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
domainAaxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy"));
```